# Is Hanamura out of the map rotation?

Tags: overwatch

I don't play Overwatch super often (like 5-15 matches a week), but still, I haven't played on Hanamura in a couple months. I understand it maybe be one of the more unbalanced maps, but has it been removed from Quick Play altogether?

Comment: This is Temple of Anubis for me, but not to the extent of never playing it for this long.

Comment: 5 downvotes? Seems a little harsh.

Comment: @DCShannon Pity upvoting is worse.

Comment: @Frank I'm perfectly happy to explain an upvote (which you seem to have assumed was me) if you're going to explain a downvote (assuming that was you), but I think I'll avoid assuming anything about your intentions, even if you'll assume something about mine. I don't see any obvious, official listing of the maps currently in rotation on the playlist. It might seem like a silly question, but it makes sense from the asker's perspective, isn't immediately solved by light research, and is well written and clear. That's a good question that it makes perfect sense to upvote.

Comment: @DCShannon You said it yourself: It seems like a silly question.  Obviously, several people think it is.  You can upvote all you like, but comments like your first do nothing but criticize voters you disagree with.  If you disagree with a vote, that's your perogative.  Whether you feel it's harsh or not is irrelevant to other voters, and has zero basis on how they vote.

Comment: Problem with this question is basically : "Are deers dead in Canada ? I can't find any in my forest nearby". There is no way to explain it because it's based on "luck". It doesn't bring much insight to people.

Comment: No it hasn't. Sometimes the same maps come up again and again, while a certain other map will come up rarely and vice versa.

Comment: Fair enough everyone, I suppose this was more of a forum-type question than an Arqade one. But, there are only 13 maps, and there was only one that I hadn't seen for roughly 80 matches; that would naturally raise suspicion. I did some quick research, and didn't find anything definitive, only articles and posts on how broken Hanamura is. So, I asked.

Comment: Perhaps link a few of the articles you speak of. I dont think there's anything wrong with Hanamura, I like it! But it would be interesting to understand what people mean when they say it's broken and/or unbalanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. You have just been "unlucky".

From personnal experience and you can also check around the Blizzard patch notes. Nothing there mentions it.
http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/21446648/

Comment: I'm assuming you're citing personal experience, but it would be good to say what you're basing this on. If you've played the map in the last few days, saying that would be plenty sufficient.